# Can Gold or Emeril be gold-starred in Galactic Market?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Title says it all really. I've been to 25 different systems in NMS and haven't ever seen gold or emeril as gold-starred items in the market. Is this event even possible? Any possible ways to increase likely-hood of offloading gold and emeril at gold-star prices?

Comment: I've never seen either or those with gold stars and I often wondered the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal experience with the game, I have never see Emeril have a gold trade star on it, however I have run into a system where Gold was starred. I do not have hard fact on whether this is an actual feature of the Galactic Market, or if it has been patched out at any time, however I do distinctly remember getting a large percent increase on Gold at one point.

Comment: I guess that's a good enough answer for now. Screenshots or something would be much appreciated, but I'll take your word for it. I don't blame NMS for at least making those systems rare. Constant 2x pricing on Gold and Emeril would  be incredibly OP

Comment: @DeepDeadpool If I ever come across it again, I'll be sure to take a screenshot. I never did before because I didn't think it was terribly important at the time. :)